# Change color of selected date in react-datepicker

Tags: css, reactjs, react-datepicker

I need to change[my react-datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL1yK.jpg) color of selected date to another color. How can I select this range of date in css?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
.react-datepicker {
  font-family: RobotoMedium;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: #c7c7c7 !important;

  &__header {
    background-color: $white !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    border: none !important;
  }

  &__day-name {
    color: #c7c7c7 !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }

  &__day {
    color: $black !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;

    &--keyboard-selected,
    &--selected {
      border-radius: 25px !important;
      background: $dark-red !important;
      color: $white !important;
    }
    &--disabled {
      color: #c7c7c7 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Use this scss, Change color like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used modular css, here.is the code

**CSS FILE**

```
.selected_day {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3ab4f1;
}
```

**JS FILE**

```
 <DatePicker
            className={`${styles.picker}`}
            value={VIEW_HISTORY}
            selected={currentDate}
            onChange={onChangeDate}
            calendarClassName={`${styles.calender}`}
            popperClassName={`${styles.popper}`}
            maxDate={MAX_DATE_LIMIT}
            minDate={MIN_DATE_LIMIT}
            dayClassName={(date) => (currentDate && (date.toDateString() === currentDate.toDateString()) ? styles['selected_day'] : styles['non_selected_day'])} // use it here

        />
```